# Attach large AWS EBS volume to AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have one AWS EC2 Instance and trying to mount with an 8TB of EBS volume. But after mounting, df -h shows 1TB mounts only. Is converting the MBR partitioning scheme to GPT the only solution? Please help

Comment: MBR limit is 2TB, not 1TB. How did you create the partitions?

Comment: I haven't created the partition yet, but only created the volume of  8TB, then mounted the volume with an existing ec2 instance. I can only see the mounted filesystem shows 1TB rather than 8TB. AWS suggests converting the MBR partitioning scheme to GPT would solve the problem. But, I'm looking for if there is any other workaround for this issue